# slice, groupBy []array

Tags: api, go, beego

I've got all servere problems by as a []array. Problem is how to slice(groupBy) status,bootable. I just wanna take as status = available, bootable = false

**Controller**

```
slicedBy := make(map[string]interface{})

server := blockstorage.ListVolumes(tenantID.(string))   <----- this is array

for _, sg := range server{
    slicedBy[sg.ID] = sg.Status                    <------- slice by Status
    slicedBy[sg.ID] = sg.Bootable                <------- slice by Bootable
}
```

**Json array**

```
{
   id        123
   status    available
   bootable  false
   ...
}
```

**server as array**

```
[
    {
        "id": "a8b123fc-a141-4682-b65b-d56899621959",
        "status": "available",
        "size": 1,
        "availability_zone": "nova",
        "attachments": [],
        "name": "snapshot 1",
        "description": "",
        "bootable": "false",
    },
    {
        "id": "ccb734d4-c098-4929-8ce5-281b6a58421d",
        "status": "error",
        "size": 2,
        "availability_zone": "nova",
        "attachments": [],
        "name": "",
        "description": "",
        "volume_type": "",
        "bootable": "false",
        "volume_image_metadata": {
            "signature_verified": "False"
        }
    },
```

Comment: May be you should use struct tags for array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for _, sg := range server {
  if(sg.Status == "available" && sg.Bootable == "false"){
     jsons["Data"] = sg
  }
}
```

It worked perfectly. I just found it.